# Return array values the match or don't match

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have an array with both website addresses and words for example...

```
$data_arr = array('www.quotes.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com',
                  'gmail.com', 'example.net', 'example.org', 'mail.com',
                  'quotes', 'google', 'yahoo', 'gmail', 'mail',
                  'example', 'moretext', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

I know I can use `strpos` or `in_array` to check if a specific string matches the array values, but is there a way to actually check for example if its a website address and return the array matches and do the opposite, checking if its a word and return the array matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`preg_grep()`](https://www.php.net/preg_grep) here.

```
$results = preg_grep('/\.[^.]*$/', $data_arr);
```

You can use `PREG_GREP_INVERT` to invert your match only returning array entries that were NOT found.

Comment: Lol, how so? Simple question

Comment: you answered it in the same minute it was asked

Comment: Alot of people answer questions fast. It's called monitoring tags for new questions and being the first to answer.

Comment: Ahh preg grep? I didnt see this!